# gevent and flask make redis w/r spend more time

Tags: python, flask, redis, gunicorn, gevent

server: ubuntu 14.04 2core and 4G.

gunicorn -k gevent and flask.

```
gunicorn==20.0.4
Flask==1.1.1
gevent==1.4.0
```

the service behind the flask is some redis read/write, just small keys and values. use the python library: redis==3.4.1.

the production problem is: when more people use same api at same time, the cost or time of the api response becomes heavy and spend more time in redis operations: from 10ms increase to 100ms or even higher.

```py
mport time
import functools
import redis
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)

pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', 
                    port='6379', 
                    db=6,
                    encoding='utf-8',
                    decode_responses=True)
r = redis.StrictRedis(
        connection_pool=pool
    )

def timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        s = time.time()
        data = request.json or request.form.to_dict()
        r = func(data, *args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print('spend: {}'.format(int(end * 1000 - s * 1000)))
        return r

    return decorator

def get_no():
    z = r.get('test2')
    print('room_no: {}'.format(z))
    if not z:
        create_no()
        return get_no()
    else:
        if player_num() > 100:
            create_no()
            return get_no()
        else:
            return z

def player_num():
    return r.incrby('room_num')

def create_no():
    if r.setnx('lock', 1):
        print('locked!')
        n = r.incrby('test2')
        r.delete('room_num')
        r.delete('lock')
        return n
    else:
        print('sleep!')
        time.sleep(0.05)


@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@timer
def test(data):
    # no = get_no()
    # print(no)
    z = r.incrby('incry_4')
    print(z)
    return jsonify(dict(code=200))
```

Plus, I take some tests in local machine with wrk tool. and found that, when use more connections , the api response spend more time. I want to know why when use the `-k gevent`, the api spend more time.

Comment: You can try with `monkey patch` like `from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()` make sure in the very beginning of your code, FYI: http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching

Comment: Define "More connections". And also, gevent won't patch redis by itself, so it will remain blocking.